# Appel de note de bas de page et virgule

Tags: typographie, ponctuation

Est-ce que la virgule se place avant ou après un appel de note en typographie française ?

[image: test, ¹ or test ²,]

Lequel est correct ? Et d'après quelle référence ?

Comment: Why do you think it should be different from English?

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: Because punctuation and formatting rules are different in English. I've just checked the *Chicago Manual of Style* and it says "The superior numerals used for note reference numbers in the text should follow any punctuation marks except the dash, which they precede. The numbers should also be placed outside closing parentheses." In French the reference numbers must be placed before the punctuation marks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L’[orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/alliage-avertissement.html#Appel_de_note) recommande de placer l’appel de note avant la virgule (et recommande une espace fine insécable avant l’appel de note, ce que L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X semble très bien faire tout seul).

Cependant, [cette discussion sur Typophile](http://typophile.com/node/60694), bien qu’elle concerne la langue anglaise, apporte des arguments qui vont dans l’autre sens. Leur consensus semble être que si la note porte sur l’ensemble de la phrase (ou de l’extrait de phrase) terminé par un point (ou une virgule), alors l’appel de note a plus de sens situé ensuite.

> Chaque semaine, nous mangions goulûment des tartes<sup>1</sup>.
>
> Chaque semaine, nous mangions goulûment des tartes.<sup>2</sup>
>
> ---
>
> 1. Les tartes aux fraises étaient à l’époque mes préférées.
> 2. Ce qui est très certainement à l’origine de mon embonpoint.

Dans le premier cas, la note se rapporte au mot « tarte », dans le second cas, à la phrase « Nous mangions […] ». Remarquons que la discussion concerne la typographie *de l’anglais*. Bien que l’argument soit logique, cela pourrait sembler inhabituel dans un texte français.

La même discussion recommande toutefois de rapprocher un peu l’exposant et la ponctuation. Peut-être L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X s’en charge-t-il là encore ? Peut-être avec le paquet microtype ?

Comment: La majeure partie de cette réponse reporte l'avis qu'on certaines personnes concernant la typographie anglaise. Celle-ci est peu normalisée (les diverses “écoles” ont généralement des avis différents), et elle est en presque tout aspect différente de la typographie française. Les appels de notes de bas de pages ne font pas exception. Concernant la typographie française seule la première phrase est pertinente.

Comment: La typographie n’est pas qu’une affaire de normes : la lisibilité du texte et sa compréhension logique sont primordiaux. Il me semble donc pertinent de proposer l’information, tout en précisant bien qu’elle provenait d’une *discussion* qui concerne la *langue anglaise*. Libre ensuite à quiconque d’en faire l’emploi qu’il désire Remarquons par ailleurs que le Chicago Manual of Style recommande apparemment de placer l’appel de note *systématiquement* après la ponctuation.

Comment: Si la question est posée ici c'est qu'elle s'intéresse à l'usage français, pas à l'usage anglais… Placer l'appel de note après une virgule c'est cohérent avec placer les guillemets (anglais) après la virgule, et on n'a certainement jamais vu ça en français, même de la part de ceux qui utilisent des guillemets anglais dans des textes en français.

Comment: Jusque là, les 10 premières recommandations que j'ai trouvées sur des sites d'éditeurs ou wikis sont unanimes. En français les appels de notes se placent avant la ponctuation (sauf dans un ou deux cas très particuliers sujets à discussion). Parmi d'autres références : http://www.myleneb.fr/appel-de-note/, http://www.cnrseditions.fr/content/8-publier-etape-3, https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aide:Note…

Answer (score 7):

Extrait du chapitre **appel de note** du *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale* :

> Dans le texte, l'appel de note se place immédiatement après le mot ou
>   le groupe de mot auquel il se rapporte et dont il est séparé soit par
>   une espace forte insécable, s'il est lui-même entre parenthèses, soit
>   par une espace fine insécable, s'il est composé en chiffres ou lettres
>   supérieurs. L'appel de note ne doit jamais être rejeté au commencement
>   d'une ligne.
>
> *L'appel de note précède donc toujours le signe de ponctuation*. En fin de phrase, il sera suivi d'un point final, même s'il est précédé
>   du point accompagnant un mot abrégé. En fin de citation, il se place
>   avant le guillemet fermant. [...]
>
> Dans un système d'appels de note entre
>   parenthèses, l'appel accompagnant une phrase elle-même entre
>   parenthèses se place entre crochet.

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour,

**Dans le cas d'une citation**, si l'Imprimerie nationale préconise dans son *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l’Imprimerie nationale* de le placer à l'intérieur des guillemets avant le signe de ponctuation (ce qui est parfaitement illogique) avec avant un espace *fine* insécable, d'autres ouvrages comme le *Manuel de typographie élémentaire*  de Perrousseaux et le *Guide du typographe* de l’Association suisse des typographes, indiquent en revanche qu'il faut le placer après les guillemets.

**Exemples :**

**1.** Règle Imprimerie nationale : « Le pouvoir lui-même n'est considéré que parce qu'il conduit à la fortune[1]. »

**2.** Règle courante plus logique : « Quand je voyais mon père se promener d'une fenêtre à l'autre, voûté, les mains derrière le dos, silencieux, le regard profond, je me demandais : “À quoi pense-t-il ?”
Aujourd'hui, je le sais par moi-même qui me promène comme lui, avec son air, et je peux répondre en toute certitude : “À rien”. »[2]

La seconde règle, plus claire et plus élégante, a tendance à remplacer aujourd'hui la vielle norme de l'Imprimerie nationale.

**Lorsqu'il ne s'agit pas d'une citation**, l'appel de note se place généralement avant le signe de ponctuation.

Cependant, les universitaires ont tendance à adopter la nouvelle règle qui consiste à placer l'appel de note là où il fait sens.

**Exemples :**

**1.** Le juriste voit l’homme dans toute sa méchanceté,[1] le théologien, dans toute sa sottise.

**2.** Le juriste voit l’homme dans toute sa méchanceté[2], le théologien, dans toute sa sottise.

[1] C'est la vision de Schopenhauer.

[2] Selon Aristote : « Si la vertu ne suffit pas à assurer le bonheur, la méchanceté suffit à rendre malheureux. » (*Ethique à Nicomaque*)

Answer (score 0):

La note se met avant, cela me parait évident sauf si, cas très particulier, la virgule ferait partie d’une citation ou de quelque chose de ce genre (et encore car alors il y aurait un guillemet fermant après).